# JFreeChart : How to make a series invisible?

Tags: jfreechart

I am trying to make a chart of ohlc bars invisible so that I can leave the window with only the moving average.
Here is the code with the two series (ohlc bars and moving average) :

```
private static JFreeChart createChart(OHLCDataset dataset)
{
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createHighLowChart(
            "HighLowChartDemo2",
            "Time",
            "Value",
            dataset,
            true);

    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();

    DateAxis axis = (DateAxis)plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setTickMarkPosition(DateTickMarkPosition.MIDDLE);
    NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis();
    yAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new DecimalFormat("$0.00"));

    //overlay the moving average dataset...
    XYDataset dataset2 = MovingAverage.createMovingAverage(dataset, "-MAVG", 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L, 0L);
    plot.setDataset(1, dataset2);
    plot.setRenderer(1, new StandardXYItemRenderer());

    XYItemRenderer theRenderer = plot.getRenderer(0);
    theRenderer.setSeriesVisible(0, false);

    return chart;
}
```

For some reason setSeriesVisible function is not working.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: The purpose is to have another plot in the same chart with moving averages and custom indicators over the price.Domain axis is stays common for both plots, using a time series.So any other suggestion that accomplishes the same thing is more than welcome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HighLowRenderer` ignores `getSeriesVisible()` and `getBaseSeriesVisible()`, although it *does* check `getDrawOpenTicks()` and `getDrawCloseTicks()`. You can replace the `OHLCDataset`:

```
plot.setDataset(0, null);
```

Alternatively, don't add the `OHLCDataset` in the first place; just use it to create the `MovingAverage`.